# Android: Wrong Scale Factor of Image in Matrix

Tags: android, matrix, zooming

I am getting wrong scale factor of the image after Zoom. I am using Matrix to get Image Scale Values. I get a scale factor but it is wrong. The original scale factor is larger than the scale factor I get through this code. The image is quite smaller than zoomed factor when I apply this scale factor to the image. 
   My Code !!!!

```
          float[] v = new float[9];
        objWatermarkImageForMerge.getMatrix().getValues(v);
          //Calculate the real scale.
            double scalex = v[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
            double skewy = v[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];



            double rScale = Math.sqrt((scalex * scalex) + (skewy * skewy));

            //Calculate the degree of rotation
            float rAngle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[Matrix.MSKEW_X], v[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));
            rotationAngle = rAngle;
```